# Python - how to filter an output in a python shell in a grep-like way?

Tags: python, grep

I work in a Python shell. In order to produce a list of all global names I use *dir*(), but it generates a very long list, which I would like to filter. I am interested only in the names which begin with 'f' and end with digits. Sometimes I also need only user-defined names, no `__*__` names. Is there any grep-like method in a Python shell to filter its output?

Comment: It won't help with the digit suffix requirement, but to *easily* list names for a prefix, try a shell with completion - e.g. bpython, ipython, dreampie, idle, spyder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[n for n in dir() if re.match("f.*[0-9]$", n)]`

I set my PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable to point to `~/.startup.py` which contains:

```
# Ned's startup.py file, loaded into interactive python prompts.

print("(.startup.py)")

import datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time

print("(imported datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time)")

def dirx(thing, regex):
    return [ n for n in dir(thing) if re.search(regex, n) ]

pp = pprint.pprint
```

Now I always have a few handy modules imported, and I have shortcuts available for things I often do in the shell.

Comment: The OP wants the names to __end__ with digits, and `re.match()` matches only at the beginning, so you need a `$` in your regex.  As it stands you are accepting `food22xyz`.  Also consider `.*?` for efficiency. #pedantic

Comment: True, true. Fixed the regex.  Since this is entered by hand for ad-hoc queries, the .*? would actually slow down the query, since the time to type (and fix the typos in) the extra character will vastly outweigh the extra time the simpler regex would use.  #takethat

Comment: The way you have written `re.match("f.*[0-9]$")` in your list comprehension does not work, does it? You either need a compiled regex pattern object or use the two arg form of `re.match(pattern,string)`

Answer (score 2):

```
[name for name in dir() if name.startswith('f') and name[-1].isdigit()]
```

Example:

```
>>> f0 = 7
>>> [name for name in dir() if name.startswith('f') and name[-1].isdigit()]
['f0']
```

Comment: it can be more digits than 1 last only

Comment: This code will check if the last character is a digit, but won't exclude filenames with a string of digits at the end of the name

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> [item for item in dir() if re.match(r'f.*\d+$',item)]
```

or

```
>>> [item for item in dir() if re.search(r'^f.*\d+$',item)]
```